# Robot wakes man from suspended animation to play Santa Claus (comic)

Tags: story-identification, comics, spaceship, suspended-animation, santa-claus

I recall a short comic story from a magazine (maybe Heavy Metal or similar) in the late 70's or early 80's.  It's about a guy who is woken from suspended animation on a colony ship by a robot once a year so the guy can put on a Santa suit and play Santa Claus.  Turns out the robot is nanny to a young boy (8 or 10 years) and the robot wants to offer the Santa experience.

The guy incapacitates the robot, grabs the kid and they head to the bridge to try to get control of the ship.  When they look out the window, the ship is crashed on a barren planetoid.

Super creepy.  Any ideas?